# How to merge multiple columns with the same table in MySQL , VBNET

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, string-concatenation

I have a datagrid that displays information of a person. And I want to do is merge the the columns(houseno,town,province,street) and display it as one. How can I do that?
Here is my codes:

```
conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=dbase"

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bs As New BindingSource

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Sql = "SELECT facultyNo AS `Faculty ID`, " & _
                        "firstname AS `Firstname` , " & _
                        "middlename AS `Middlename` , " & _
                        "lastname AS `Lastname` , " & _
                        "gender AS `Gender` , " & _
                        "homeadd_houseno & homeadd_brgy & homeadd_street & homeadd_town AS `Home Address` , " & _ "THIS IS WHAT I WANTED"
                        "tersiary_schoolname AS `School Name` , " & _
                        "tersiary_address AS `School's Address` , " & _
                        "tersiary_degree AS `Degree` , " & _
                        "tersiary_batch AS `Batch` , " & _
                        "birthdate AS `Birthdate` , " & _
                        "contact_mobileno AS `Mobile No.` , " & _
                        "contact_telno AS `Telephone No.` , " & _
                        "age AS `Age` , " & _
                        "collegeSchool AS `Tersiary` , " & _
                        "schoolAdd AS `School's Address` , " & _
                        "emailAdd AS `Email Address` , " & _
                        "contactno AS `Contact Number` " & _
                        "FROM dbase.tblfacultyinfo"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        bs.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
        da.Update(dt)

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

```
select concat (homeadd_houseno,', ',homeadd_brgy,', ',homeadd_street,', ',homeadd_town ) AS `Home Address` 
from
dbase.tblfacultyinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses '+' not '&' for string concatenation, so try...

```
homeadd_houseno + ' ' + homeadd_brgy + ' ' + homeadd_street + ' ' + homeadd_town AS `Home_Address`
```